# If $A^3=-E$ then does $A=-E$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

$E$ is the identity matrix.
$A$ is a 2 by 2 matrix where $A^3$ is equal to $-E$. Then does $A=-E$

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Take $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. What is $A^3$? When is it equal to $-\operatorname{Id}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1+i\sqrt3}{2}&0 \\ 
0 & \frac{1-i\sqrt3}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
from above $A\neq -E$

but if you take cube of above matrix you will get 
$$A^3=-E$$